# Automatically wrap multiple images in div

Tags: functions, customization, images, content

There are a few questions that are similar to this but I have not found anything that works with the latest version of WordPress.
I am trying to wrap adjacent images into the one div.

```
<p>
  <img> />
  <img> />
  <img> />
  Some text.
</p>
```

into:

```
<p>
 <div>
  <img> />
  <img> />
  <img> />
 </div>  
Some text.
</p>
```

I can wrap each image into its own div using:

```
function wrapImagesInDiv($content) {
   $pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>)/i';
   $replacement = '<div>$1</div>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrapImagesInDiv');
```

and I think it would be possible to edit the regex to wrap multiple img tags using {2,} but have failed to get it to work.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Thanks to Beee, this works for my needs but feels very clunky. Any improvements welcome.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_wrapper', 99, 1 );
function add_image_wrapper( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace_callback( '/<img[^>]+>|<p>|<br>/im',
        function( $matches ) use (&$inimg) {

        $fulltag   = $matches[0];    
        preg_match('/<(img)[^>]+>|<(p)>|<(br)>/',$fulltag,$tag);  

        $tag = $tag[1];

        if ( $tag === 'img') {
            ( $inimg == true) ? $tag = 1 : $tag = 0;
            ( $inimg == false ) ? $inimg = true : $inimg;
        }                          
        else {
            ( $inimg == true) ? $tag = 2 : $tag = 3;                    
            ( $inimg == true ) ? $inimg = false : $inimg;
        }

        switch ($tag) {
          case 0: //no preceding img tag
              return sprintf( '<div>%s', $fulltag );
              break;
          case 1: //preceding img tag
              return sprintf( '%s', $fulltag );
              break;
          case 2: //last image tag
              return sprintf( '</div>%s', $fulltag );
              break;
          case 3:
              return sprintf( '%s', $fulltag );
              break;
       }
    }, $content );

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: `/(([| ]{0,}(<img.+?\/>)[\s|\n| ]{0,}){3})/i` is about as far as I got, but i give up. worked to find three images, but changing `{3}` to `{0,}` just messed everything up. not an answer, but maybe it'll help.

Comment: what you want to get is a broken HTML. DIV should not be in a P

Comment: I know the P tag is wrong as a wrapper for a DIV, but it's what WorPress spits out for the post. I know I can manually edit the page to reformat it but my users won't necessarily be confident to do this. My other option is a custom post format.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I use to add a wrapper to each image. I know it's not 100% what you want, but I thought this might give you a handle to work from.

```
function add_image_wrapper( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace_callback( '/<img[^>]+>/im', function ( $matches ) {
        $image   = $matches[0];
        $classes = array();
        preg_match( '/class="align([^"]+)"/im', $image, $classes );

        $align = ( ! empty( $classes ) ? $classes[1] : null );
        $class = '';
        if ( in_array( $align, array( 'left', 'right' ) ) ) {
            $class = 'media--align-' . $align;
        }

        return sprintf(
            '<div class="media %s">%s</div>',
            $class, $image
        );
    }, $content );

    // Remove unnecessary classes from media-wrappers inside figures
    $content = preg_replace_callback( '/<figure[^>]+>.+<\/figure>/im', function ( $matches ) {
        $figure = $matches[0];

        return preg_replace( '/class="media[^"]+"/im', 'class="media"', $figure );
    }, $content );

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_wrapper', 99, 1 );
```

Comment: Great idea to use the callback. I have edited original question with a working solution. I'm not a fan of all of the conditionals and I'm sure there are situations where it will break, but I'd be interested to see if anyone can improve it.

Comment: Can you use a gallery for this ? Because a gallery already has defined containers/classes.